# Reset position of all objects on UICollectionViewCell [iOS]

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to reset the frames / positions of the views on my collectionviewcell.  There is a background view that updates its size of based on the content.  Everything is using AutoLayouts.

How do I reset the frame position of the cell using: dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the state of your cell, then the best way to do it would be to override `prepareForReuse` method. What exactly you do in that method depends on your cell's layout.
Documentation is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse